# Parsing Soap response - XML/XPATH (In soapUI) (namespace in SoapUI response)

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, soapui

If I've a Soap response like below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns0:SomeResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:ABC:EFG:HIJ:Some_WS">
         <ns0:ID>6384</ns0: ID>
         <ns0:Some_ID>10530</ns0: Some_ID >
         <ns0:Status>SomeStatus</ns0:Status>
         <ns0:Number>INT1037;INT1027;</ns0: Number>
      </ns0:SomeResponse >
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I retrieve `Some_ID` value. I am using the below code in SoapUI to retrieve the value of `Some_ID`.

```
...
def response = tstep.getPropertyValue("response");
def gutils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def holder = gutils.getXmlHolder("$response");
// define namespace
holder.namespaces["ns0"] = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
def val1 = holder.getNodeValue("//ns0:SomeResponse/ns0:Some_ID");
log.info(val1)
```

But `log.info` is giving me `null` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve just that one specific value, you can use a simple:

```
def val1 = context.expand('${TestStepName#Response#//*:Some_ID}')
```

For more complex parsing, you would have use to either `XmlHolder` or `XmlParser` or `XmlSlurper`. You can get an idea about these from the [official documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html).

In your script, try using `tstep.getPropertyValue("Response")`, with upper-case R.

Comment: tried. Its working your way too. But just wondering why everywhere I searched , people asked to declare  `namespaces` in case it is a Soap response.

Comment: Because most people do not understand namespaces in XML. For *writing* XML, they are essential. For *reading* XML, they are optional. For reading simple XML, such as your case, they unnecessarily complicate things.

Comment: @SiKing totally agree `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I had to change `namespaces` declaration to below and thats it.

```
holder.namespaces["ns0"] = "urn:ABC:EFG:HIJ:Some_WS"
```