# SoapUI 5.0.0 json property moving

Tags: json, xpath, soapui, assertion

I'm trying to move a property resulted from json response.
The property is a child from an array.
I tried to get it with declaring namespace like this:

```
*declare namespace ns="http://localhost:9090/opale-api-1.1.x/commande/${RenouvellementInfo#refCommande}/transformerEnContrat";
//ns:referencesContrats[0]*
```

Notice that response contains only json (`</xml>`)

Thank you very much for your precious help!

Comment: may be  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223774/parsing-soap-response-xml-xpath-in-soapui-namespace-in-soapui-response)

Comment: Would you like to show the `raw response`? If the response is **json**, it may not be showing any _xml_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of groovy script assertion and JSONSlupper API

http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/How-do-i-get-JSON-values-from-a-response-in-Groovy/td-p/19417

http://onetestsolution.com/blog/reading-json-request-and-response-in-soapui-using-groovy-scripting/